# What is the base and dim for the kernel of this linear transformation version2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Ok, so i have a linear transformation that is from second degree polynomial to a $2\times 2$ matrix

$$T : \mathbf{P_{2}[X]} \to \mathbb{R^{2\times2}}$$

which defined as:

$$T(P(X)) = \begin{pmatrix} P(1) & P(0) \\ P(-1) & P(0) \end{pmatrix}$$

I have been asked to find the dim and the base for the kernel of $T$.

what I did was:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a+b+c & a \\ a-b+c & a \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

so I got:

$a=0, b=c, b = -c \implies b=c=0=a$

I wanted to know if I was right...
So after I calculated it, it turned out that $\ker(T) = 0$. and therefore there is not a base for it.

or second option is that in this case any vector from $\mathbf{P_{2}[X]}$ goes to the zero matrix,
and therefore the base for the kernel in this case is the standard base of
$\mathbf{P_{2}[X]}$ which is {(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}
????

I will be more than happy to know what am i missing here...

Comment: $T$ has got a kernel that contains the polynomials which are going to the zero. Because $T(P)$ represents a linear transform for every $P$, it has got a kernel too, but it depends on $P$ and differs from $T$'s kernel ($\ker T(P)$ contains vectors not polynomials). You gave $T$ kernel with your first computation.

Comment: can u explain further?

Comment: How? Your first computation determines $\ker T$, the second determines $\ker T(P)$ in the case when $P\in\ker T$. Since $T$ and $T(P)$ are different things, it is not very surprising, that $\ker T$ differs from $\ker T(P)$. As you said you had to search $\ker T$.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is correct. So, now the question is, how to interpret the calculation.

What did you compute: You took an arbitrary second-degree polynomial $P(X)=a+bX+cX^2$ and computed $T(P(X)$. It turned out that $T(P(X))=0$ if and only if $a=b=c=0$. In this case $P(X)=0$, the constant-zero polynomial. So, $\operatorname{ker}(T)=\{0\}$. Whether you say that there is a basis for the zero vector space or not depends on your conventions. Many people will say that $\emptyset$ is a basis for the zero vector space.

The other option would occur when you calculated $\tilde{T}(P(X))$ for some other linear map $\tilde{T}$ and it turned out that $\tilde{T}(P(X))$ for all $P(X)$. Then you could deduce that $\operatorname{ker}(\tilde{T})=P_2(X)$. In this case, a standard basis is given by $\{1,X,X^2\}$. The "standard basis" you gave will not be contained in $P_2(X)$.

Comment: Did you mean $\tilde{T}(P(X))=0$ for all $P(X)$?

Comment: @user84413 Yes, for all, or equivalently for a basis of $P_2(X)$.